# How to find words with a specific letter using RegExp?

Tags: regex, dart

```dart
void main() {
  var string = 'This is a statement with i.';
  var regExp = RegExp('i');
  for (var match in regExp.allMatches(string)) {
    print(match.group(0));
  }
}
```

I want to print all the words which has `i` in it by **only using `RegExp`**. For instance, the above for loop should print

```
This
is
with
i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would checking for a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) work for you?

The pattern `\b\w*i\w*\b` with the `global` flag set matches:

```
This
is
with
i
```

[Try it out!](https://regex101.com/r/WmGMSv/1)

---

I don't have access to my GitHub (to share a gist) at the moment, but this pattern works as expected in DartPad.

[image]

Comment: It only prints `This is`, I'm using `RegExp(r'\b\w*i\w*\b');` as you said.

Comment: I believe you need the `r` [raw string](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) identifier if you're going to use the literal pattern. Try `RegExp(r"\b\w*i\w*\b");`.

Comment: In Dart String `'` and `"` are interchangeable. So, even this `RegExp(r"\b\w*i\w*\b")` printed only `This is`

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, then. I had the same problem the first time I ran the code in DartPad, but it's worked since. Maybe someone with more Dart experience has a better answer for you.

Comment: This answer should be correct.  I think that [DartPad is just temporarily broken](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/1841).

Comment: @jamesdlin AFAIR, I ran the code in macOS app and it actually printed `this is` initially, but now it's printing all the words. Strange!